# Size Classes & Plus Phone

Tags: ios, swift, device, size-classes, iphone-6-plus

So all phones have compact width/regular height in portrait. Plus phones have regular width/compact height in landscape while others have compact width/compact height.

So the only in LANDSCAPE orientation you can distinguish a plus model phone.

---

### Question

Is there a way to distinguish a plus model phone in portrait orientation?

*without checking for:*

- *Screen resolution*
- *Screen scale*
- *Device strings*

---

[image]

---

**NOTE:**

Checking for screen resolution/scale, device strings are plausible, however trying to stay away from those. For example, Apple had to put Contact Icons for Favorites for iPhone Plus in Portrait.  So there has to be a formal way to do this?

Comment: dude! apple can do many things we can't. e.g.animated app icon like clock. :(. All we can see is the restriction.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting it wrong. The main purpose to make the adaptive layout is it can adapt to any screen size irrespective of device.

You should not think about these devices screen size while making layouts. You should be thinking of size classes.

If your layout can work in above size classes than it should work in respective phones. Also if you are looking for orientation but your app support the multitasking than your layout might not work with that.

Ideally, Your app should have layout that can work in any screen size because apple is releasing new devices with different screen sizes so your app should be compatible and work in every layout.

But that is ideal world. You can handle most of your layout with size classes. In some cases you need to handle the special scenarios.